# Eclipse RCP e4: how to add a progress bar with unknown work load

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I want to add a progressbar to my RCP e4 application that only indicates that some bg-work is running. No progress report needed, just a rolling bar like below:

[image]

My question is how to do that? Do I need to implement this control myself? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html and IIRC there is a constant something like `SWT.INDETERMINATE` you can use when you create the progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the lowest level you can use the SWT `ProgressBar` control with the `SWT.INDETERMINATE` flag.

JFace extends this with the `ProgressIndicator` class which supports both determinate and indeterminate bars. It extends this further with the `ProgressMonitorPart` which provides a cancel button and implements the `IProgressMonitorWithBlocking` interface.

If you are using `Job` in e4 you need to hook up the UI progress bar to the job manager by setting the progress provider using:

```java
Job.getJobManager().setProgressProvider(provider);
```

where `provider` is a class extending `ProgressProvider`. This class provides the job system with the progress monitor to use when jobs are running. This can be based on a `ProgressMonitorPart`.

Comment: Thanks for the so detailed answer! I'm using ProgressBar with SWT.INDETERMINATE flag now.

Comment: Basically only a single ProgressProvider is allowed. So if I provide my own, then every job runs on that one, right?

Comment: @LppEdd Just the one progress provider is used for all jobs. A traditional Eclipse 3.x style RCP already has a provider (org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager), I don't know what would happen if you tried to change it. I have only ever used this in a pure e4 RCP.